# How to numerically solve the Poisson equation given Neumann boundary conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation

I want to solve the Poisson equation on a 2D domain given Neumann-type boundary conditions:

The PDE:
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 \; u(r,\theta) \;=\; f(r,\theta)
\end{equation}

The boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \big|_{r\rightarrow r_{min}} =&\; A(r_{min},\theta)\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \big|_{r\rightarrow r_{min}} =&\; A(r_{max},\theta) \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} \big|_{\theta\rightarrow \theta_{min}} =&\; B(r,\theta_{min})\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} \big|_{\theta\rightarrow \theta_{max}} =&\; B(r,\theta_{max})
\end{align}

The solution to this problem is unique only up to an additive, uniform constant: 
\begin{equation}
u(r,\theta) = u(r,\theta) + c\text{,} \qquad \text{where $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{\nabla}c=0$.}
\end{equation}

That's fine with me, since I am only interested in the *gradient* of $u(r,\theta)$ anyway.

I try to solve this equation implicitly using a 2nd order, 2D finite difference (FD) approach, with a centered FD scheme for the first and second derivatives in the interior and a right- or left-sided FD scheme for the boundaries (to avoid using ghost points). On the boundaries, I substitute the boundary constraint functions for the appropriate first derivative. The matrix equation looks vaguely like the following:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} & & & & & & & & & \\ & & & & & & & & & \\ & & & & & & & & & \\ & & & & & & & & & \\ & & & & & M & & & & \\ & & & & & & & & & \\ & & & & & & & & & \\ & & & & & & & & & \\  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u_{1,1} \\ u_{1,2} \\ u_{1,3} \\ \dots \\ u_{2,1} \\ u_{2,2} \\ \dots \\ u_{N,M} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} f_{1,1} \\ f_{1,2} \\ f_{1,3} \\ \dots \\ f_{2,1} \\ f_{2,2} \\ \dots \\ f_{N,M} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The problem is that the matrix is singular. This is to be expected, however, since the solution is not unique! An infinite number of solutions exist, so the matrix equation does not have a unique solution either.

### My question is this:

**How can I numerically solve this problem?**

Should I specify the value of $u(r,\theta)$ at some point to make the solution unique (e.g. $u(r^\star,\theta^\star)=c$)? If so, how can this be done? If not, how else could I solve the equation—without a singular matrix? Is there a way to solve directly for $\vec{\nabla} u(r,\theta)$?

I am happy to use a pre-made matrix solver routine, as long as I know which algorithm (e.g. SVD, LU, etc.) it uses.

I think this is generally applicable!

Comment: Simply throw away some $(i,j)$-th equation and replace it with $u_{i,j} = c$ equation. Though, that would break symmetry your system may have. The other way is to eliminate $u_{i,j}$ variable completely from the system, substituting $c$ for it, that would preserve symmetry.

Comment: @uranix: The first approach won't work for me because I need to enforce the governing equation at all points. I have already tried your second approach, and found that the matrix equation wasn't solvable because it had no constraints on the $u_{i,j}$ term.

Comment: The govering equation is already enforced at $u_{i,j}$ since it is just a consequence of all other equations (linear dependence). You should not constrain $u_{i,j}$ at all, you need to eliminate it, so it no more is a part of the system. Like
$$
x + y = 1\\
x + 2y + z = 2\\
y + z = 1
$$
Letting $y = c$ we could eliminate $y$
$$
x = 1-c\\
z = 1-c
$$

Comment: @uranix: I wrote a 1D test code and confirmed that the equation is satisfied. That's really cool! (I wish I could give you +5 rep instead of +1). How does that work out, though? Is it just because the PDE is a linear PDE? Under what conditions would it have problems?

Comment: @uranix: Also, what do you mean by it breaking symmetry?

Comment: By breaking symmetry I've meant
$$
x + y = 1\\x + 2y + z = 2\\y + z = 1
$$
has a symmetrical matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ and
$$
x + y = 1\\
y = 0\\
y + z = 1
$$
does not, since its matrix is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\0 & 1  & 0\\0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Please also take a look at additions to my post below

Comment: I tried solving $D u''(x) + u'(x) = f(x)$ given appropriate BCs problems. When I took the first approach (throwing away the $u_{i}$-th row/equation and replacing it with $u_{i} = C$), that approach effectively split the domain into two sides. One side had a Neumann boundary condition (BC) at $x_0$ and a Dirichlet BC at $x_i$, and the other half had the same Dirichlet BC at $x_i$ and a Neumann BC at $x_N$. For 2nd order FD scheme, the two sides were completely isolated. This caused a discontinuity at the specified point $x_i$. It worked well when $f=0$ (the Laplace eqn), but not generally.

Comment: Did you try some problem with an analytical solution? E.g. take $u = \sin x$ and $f = -D \sin x + \cos x$ and check if discontinuity goes away? That really seems like ill-posed problem to me.

Comment: I used this as the solution: $u(x) = A\left( e^{-Bx} - e^{-Bw} \right) + C$, which satisfies this BVP: $Du″(x)+u′(x)=f(x)$, $u'(0) = -AB$, $u'(L) = -AB e^{-BL}$, $u(w) = C$, where the domain is $0 \le x \le L$ and the specified point is $u(w)=C$, where $0 < w < L$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matrix has icomplete rank, so the system is solvable only if
$$
\operatorname{rank} M = \operatorname{rank} \begin{pmatrix}M \;\big|\;  f\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Due to truncation error, the last may not hold (but would hold, if you're using a conservative approximation, I suppose).

You can use QR decomposition to deal with that. Suppose $M = QR$ where $Q$ is orthogonal and $R$ is upper triangular matrix. The rank of $R$ is equal to the rank of $M$ and that is one less than number of its rows. So
$$
R = \begin{pmatrix}
\star & \star & \dots & \star & \star\\
0 & \star & \dots & \star & \star\\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \star & \star\\
0 & 0 & \dots & \star & \star\\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}R' & h\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
Solving the system $Mx = f$ is equivalent to solving the system
$$
Rx=Q^\top f \equiv \begin{pmatrix}z'\\\alpha\end{pmatrix}, \alpha \in \mathbb R.
$$
For the system to have a solution the last element $\alpha$ of $Q^\top f$ should be zero. Even if it's not, let's fix it as zero. Let's also fix the last element of $x$ as zero, since it can be any number.
$$
x = \begin{pmatrix}x'\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now we have a nonsingular triangular system
$$
R' x' = z'
$$
which can easily be solved.

Note, that for the scheme you're using matrix $M$ is sparse, so you need sparse version of $QR$ decomposition. Also, since $Q$ is not sparse for QR even if $M$ was, you need to perform QR for extended matrix $(M|f)$ to compute both $R = Q^\top M$ and $Q^\top f$ at the same time.

**Appendix**

I've implemented this method in Matlab and also the method of one equation elimination. For correct problems they give the same solution.
For testing purposes I used square domain $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ and the following problem
$$
\Delta u = 0\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = g(x, y), \quad (x,y) \in \partial G.
$$
This problem has well known solvability criterion, that is
$$
0 = \left(\int_G \Delta u dx dy = \int_{\partial G} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} d\Gamma\right) = \int_{\partial G} g d\Gamma
$$
Due to numerical errors it never can be exactly achieved, so from exact  mathematical point of view, the numerical problem is always ill-posed. So we have to deal with regularized problem, that is to solve a problem with 
$$
\int_{\partial G} g d \Gamma \neq 0.
$$
That's where the methods differ. They eliminate the inconsistency in various ways.

### Equation elimination

When we are using equation elimination, that is removing one governing equation and replacing it with 
$$
u_{i,j} = 0
$$
for example, we state that all the inconsistency should eliminated via $(i,j)$ point. In fact, the real problem we are solving now is
$$
\Delta u = \delta(x - x_i, y - y_i) \int_{\partial G} g d\Gamma\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = g(x, y), \quad (x,y) \in \partial G.
$$
so we put a source or a sink at $x_i, y_i$ to resolve the inconsistency. For the test problem I want $u(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{y^2}{2}$ to be the solution, so 
$$
g(-1, y) = 1,\quad g(1, y) = 1\\
g(x, -1) = -1, \quad g(x, 1) = -1
$$
Do demonstrate the effect of inconsistency I would take $g(x, -1) = 0.5$.
[image]
Note the pole-like thing at the middle - that was the point with $u_{i,j} = 0$ equation. At every other point the function satisfies $\Delta u = 0$ and the boundary conditions.

### QR method

Again, let
$$
Mu = f
$$
be decomposed as
$$
Mu \equiv QRP^\top u = f\\
RP^\top u = Q^\top f.
$$
I've added permutation matrix $P$ to allow column reordering of the matrix $M$ which improves sparse QR a lot.

Let again,
$$
R = \begin{pmatrix}
R' & h\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \quad Q^\top f = \begin{pmatrix}
z'\\\alpha
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So we state that
$$
x = \begin{pmatrix}
R^{-1} z'\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a regularized solution to
$$
Rx = z \Leftrightarrow Mx = f
$$
since $Mx = f$ simply does not have a solution. But what is the real problem we are solving now?

Recall that $M$ is singular, we also know its left zeroing vector. Let $\omega = \frac{1}{\|\omega\|}(1, 1, \dots, 1)^\top$. Then
$$
\omega^\top M
$$
is simply the sum of every row of $M$ and that is zero (actually, it is implementation-dependent, but the idea remains the same). So the last row of $R$ is nothing more than $\omega^\top M$, and $\alpha = \omega^\top f \sim \int_{\partial G} g d\Gamma$ (up to some constant multiplication).

If we plug the regularized solution $x$ to the system $Rx = z$ we observe a residual:
$$
R x \neq z,\quad R x = z + \begin{pmatrix}0\\-\alpha\end{pmatrix}
$$
and by multiplying by $Q$ we have
$$
Mx = f - \alpha \omega
$$
since $\omega$ is exactly the last column of $Q$. So now we are solving a problem where inconsistency is smoothed over the whole domaing $G$ and its border $\partial G$, roughly speaking
$$
\Delta u = -\frac{1}{|G|} \int_{\partial G} g d\Gamma
$$

This method applied to the same problem gives the following solution
[image]

It looks fine, but, actually, the equation is violated (slightly) at every node and boundary conditions are also violated (also slightly).

Finally, there's no much difference what method to use if you're solving a well-posed problem, like arising from 
$$
\nabla \phi = \mathbf E \Rightarrow \Delta \phi = \operatorname{div} \mathbf E.
$$

The Matlab code I've used you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/uranix/528e8faaf2775bd23a8d)

Comment: AWESOME answer! Thanks! I do have a few follow-up questions...rep for each if you can answer them. :-)   Q1: The indexing of the loop on line 26 makes sense because it's setting up the du/dy BCs from the min X to the max X (corner-to-corner). The loop starting on line 42 (handling du/dx BCs) doesn't hit the corner points (j=1,j=M+1). Is that a mistake? Q2: Is the QR approach essentially calculating a least-squares (rather than a direct) solution, and if so, is there any loss of accuracy?

Comment: Q3: (important to my application!) How would this change for a Poisson equation of the form $\nabla^2 \Phi(x,y) = f(x,y)$ (2D), or even $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = f(x)$ (1D)? In particular, does the line-replacement approach still work? I'm concerned that by replacing $\frac{1}{h^2}\left(u_{i+1} - 2 u_{i} + u_{i-1}\right) = f_{i}$ with $ u_{i} = C$ (for some C), the information/constraint provided by $f_i$ will be lost. That seems to be the case in my own code.

Comment: @jvriesem A1: Corner points are useless, they really should be omitted, but I've included them in left and right boundary. They should not be included twice. A2: QR is perfectly direct method. The only loss is due to (possibly) incorrect statement and numerical roundoff errors. A3: Generally speaking, if you are hitting a singular system and see that singularity is due to multiple solutions, you are free to eliminate one equation and replace it with some condition to fix the unique solution. Should work for any problem with Neumann conditions, even nonlinear

Comment: Information is not lost, That information is still present in assumption about solvability of the problem. That is $\int_{\partial G} g d\Gamma = 0$ for Laplace equation, the eliminated value $f_i$ actually is determined from all other $f_j$

Comment: Also, you mention the permutation matrix $P$. Is that implemented in your code in any way? (I'm new to the QR approach, so I'm using your code and answer to learn.)

Comment: Last question! I checked the boundary conditions manually via a three-stencil FD method, for the working case when `bbc = @(x, y)  y;`. I found that the derivatives on the boundaries were consistently +/- 1.0172. For example, `bbc(h*(0:M)-1,-1)` is `-1`, but calculating the derivative by hand gives `-1.0172`. Thus the boundary conditions are being violated. Is there any way to ensure that they are enforced?

Comment: Shouldn't all of the boundary conditions hold at the corner points, too? I'm not thinking of having two different rows for a given boundary condition, but rather making two substitutions, one for each BC on the corner: $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \big|_{1,1} \rightarrow \frac{2}{h^2} \left( u_{2,1}- u_{1,1} - h \text{bbc}_{1,1}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \big|_{1,1} \rightarrow \frac{2}{h^2} \left( u_{1,2}- u_{1,1} - h \text{lbc}_{1,1}\right)$. My thinking is that each corner point should be subject to the BCs just like all other points on the boundaries.